# Traffic on Apple TV asleep

Tags: network, sleep-wake, appletv, airplay

I just bought an Apple TV 4k and I discovered that there is some network activity when the Apple TV is asleep (light off).

x.x.x.x is the apple tv ip address.
This is a summary (ip address / port).

[image]

What is this activity?

I filtered the port 7000 because it seems the Apple TV connects to every device on the lan for AirPlay.

Is there a real sleep mode?
Which settings can stop these connections?

Comment: 2.16.x.x and 23.211.x.x addresses are Akamai. 17.179.x.x and 17.57.x.x are Apple. These connections most likely are used by Apple to check for various services and software updates, sharing anonymous performance data, etc. [This handy page at Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944) shows the TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products. TCP port 5223 in particular is used for iCloud DAV Services (Contacts, Calendars, Bookmarks), Push Notifications, FaceTime, iMessage, Game Center, Photo Stream.

Comment: I set "software update" to no and say no to "sharing analysis data" and i don't use iCloud.

Comment: @iconDeamon Apple fix this issue after 15.1.1 update on apple tv. There is no more traffic on apple tv when apple tv is sleeping. It took 6 months for apple to fix this bug.